# Disable Karabiner complex rule on some keyboard combination

Tags: keyboard, spotlight, karabiner, mapping

I would like to enable the following rule which sets the spacebar to left shift when pressed together with another key. The problem is that this disables spotlight search (which uses CMD+spacebar).

Is there a way to disable the spacebar rule when pressed with the command key? An alternative way would be to set the cmd + spacebar to spotlight in Karabiner itself. Is that a possibility (I could find it anywhere the documentation)

```
                    {
                    "description": "Change spacebar to left_shift. (Post spacebar if pressed alone)",
                    "manipulators": [
                        {
                            "from": {
                                "key_code": "spacebar",
                                "modifiers": {
                                    "optional": [
                                        "any"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "to": [
                                {
                                    "key_code": "left_shift"
                                }
                            ],
                            "to_if_alone": [
                                {
                                    "key_code": "spacebar"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "basic"
                        }
                    ]
                }
```